# Rails seed data into custom databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

My Rails setup has multiple databases, few others than the `development`, `test`, and `production`. When I do `rails db reset`, it doesn't drop/create any of the custom databases I have. What am I missing?

My database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 15
  host: postgres
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password:

development:
  <<: *default
  database: site_dev
site1:
  <<: *default
  database: site1
site2:
  <<: *default
  database: site2
site3:
  <<: *default
  database: site3
test:
  <<: *default
  database: site_test
production:
  <<: *default
  database: site_prod
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work. Because each database is associated with the different environments in the system. When you reset the db it resets databases that belong to that environment. In your case if you want to reset these databases you need to associate them to an environment.